# can't detect arabic text on MS excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to detect arabic text from cell.

I am writing a program to detect the Arabic numbers from alphanumeric Arabic text.

Unfortunately, I am unable to get it.

If the cell consists of only arabic numbers, then I can get it, but if the value in cell is alphanumeric,
then it is considered whole as char.

The program is:

```
Sub ReverseText()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    xValue = "       " & xValue
    xLen = VBA.Len(xValue)
    xOut = ""
    yOut = ""
        'Trying to reverse the arabic char
        For i = 1 To xLen
        getchar = VBA.Right(xValue, 1)

            'Checking if String contain numbers or not
            If IsNumeric(getchar) Then
            xValue = VBA.Left(xValue, xLen - i)
            yOut = getchar & yOut

            'If not numers then check for decimal point
            Else
                If getchar = "." Then
                xValue = VBA.Left(xValue, xLen - i)
                yOut = getchar & yOut
                'xOut = xOut & yOut
                getchar = ""

                'If not numbers then check for char other than numbers
                Else
                    xValue = VBA.Left(xValue, xLen - i)
                    xOut = xOut & yOut
                    xOut = xOut & getchar
                    yOut = ""
                End If
            End If

        Next

        Rng.Value = xOut
    Next
End Sub
```

Value in cell is:

```
ARABIAN COLA CAN 355ML X 20
```

after running the program, the output should be:

```
20 X LM355 NAC ALOC NAIBARA
```

This is in English, and it is working properly.
Now in Arabic

The value in the cell is:

```
٦*ﻝﻣ٣٥٥ﻛﺎﻣ ﻲﺳﺑﺑ
```

and the output by this program:

```
ﺑﺑﺳﻲ ﻣﺎﻛ٥٥٣ﻣﻝ*٦
```

Alphabets are reversing properly, but numbers also, which should not be.

I need the output to be similar to the English text one. 
But the program is not detecting Arabic numbers.

I am using excel2011 mac.

I tried in windows 7 also but there is also the same problem.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Said that I don't know anything about Arabic language (so sorry if I say something that doesn't make sense), the function `IsNumeric()` recognizes numericals 0-9 only as numeric.

My suggestion is to develop and add your own `IsArabNumeric()` function. You might first of all copy and paste the numbers into a range of a sheet, let's say that you put them into the range `A1:A10` of the sheet `MySheet`. Then, the function would look something like this:

```
Public Function IsArabNumeric(ByVal char As String) As Boolean
    For j = 1 To 10
        If Sheets("MySheet").Range("A" & j).Value = char Then
            IsArabNumeric = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next j
    IsArabNumeric = False
End Function
```

So, instead of doing this check :

```
'Checking if String contain numbers or not
 If IsNumeric(getchar) Then
```

you would do this and it should work:

```
'Checkin if String contain arabic numbers or not
If IsArabNumeric(getchar) Then
```

Please note: there might be more elegants way, such as see in which position of the collection `Chr()` the arabic numbers are and looping through them rather than having to copy-paste these values into a separate sheet (which is not really elegant from a coding point of view)... but this is intended to be a tip, you can have a look yourself into the [Chr collection](http://www.gtwiki.org/mwiki/?title=VB_Chr_Values) and readapt the idea.